# Extjs6:Error running sencha ant sass command

Tags: extjs, ant, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am new to extjs. I have created an extjs 6.0.2 app through sencha cmd. I ran the command **sencha app build classic**.everything went well and the app was created successfully.but when I ran the command **sencha ant sass**, I got the following error in the console

```
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.chart.LegendBase for file  Ext.chart.Legend
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.chart.LegendBase
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 3 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Workspace\Zscore\zscore\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:382: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.chart.LegendBase
```

what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add charts in requires array of app.json

Comment: Yes, it is there. That is why sencha app build command is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

from the Extjs forum:

I believe that you'll need to specify which build profile is being targeted. Something like this: sencha ant -Dbuild.id=classic -Dbuild.name=classic sass

Forum link: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?314286-Extjs6-Error-running-sencha-ant-sass-command

Comment: Avoid posting links because those can go dead. Note that this question is 7 months old.

Comment: While the forum post link is bad, the build.id and build.name really helps!

Without this you can get dependency issues.